# Remove some layout elements from JProgressBar

Tags: java, jprogressbar

I would like to know if it's possible to remove red areas(on JProgressBar) on the following image.

[image: JProgressBar]

These are blue lines on the top and left side of the progress bar which I would like to remove. I have managed to remove it with paint() method, painting progress bar manually. But probably there is more correct way of doing it.

Thanks,
Serhiy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested but i think progressBar.setBorderPainted(false) should do the trick.

Comment: Damn, thank you! I was lloking this function and didn't tested it too lol! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Subclassing `JProgressBar`and overriding `paint()`is fine and perfectly correct if you want to modify the bar's behaviour. I'm not sure where your blue lines are coming from though; do you have a shadow effect set somewhere?

Comment: Looks like the default Metal L&F progress bar to me, except for the green background.